# How to remove trailing slashes from URL with .htaccess in localhost?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

*Here is my localhost folder structure:*

```
•www (wamphost folder)

    •example.com (folder)

        •index.php
```

*With the current the URL results:*

```
localhost/example.com/
```

*The URL I would like is:*

```
localhost/example.com
```

*What I would like:*

My intention is remove the slash beside URL, but I tried so many ways and still no clue how. I am new to rewrites and no matter how I change the URL keep adding the slash by itself.

*My .htaccess file:*

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex index.php
DirectorySlash Off    

RewriteRule ^example.com$ /domain.com/index.php [L,E=LOOP:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_LOOP} !1
RewriteRule ^example.com/$ /domain.com [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_LOOP} !1
RewriteRule ^example.com/index.php$ /domain.com [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the `DirectorySlash Off` directive, what you are probably seeing is a cached redirect.

Normally, mod_dir (`DirectorySlash On`) will append a slash when requesting a real directory (this is required to make the request valid) by issuing a 301 redirect to the slashed URL. 301 (permanent) redirects are naturally cached by the browser.

In order to still serve the `DirectoryIndex` then you need to now do this manually yourself and *internally rewrite* to the slashed URL, or explicitly to the index document (eg. `index.php`) if this is known. Otherwise you'll likely get a 403 Forbidden (unless mod_autoindex is configured to generate a directory listing).

So, something like the following:

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]
```

The mod_rewrite directives state... for all URLs that don't end in a slash that do map to physical directories then internally rewrite and append a slash. This will then allow mod_dir to further rewrite the request and serve the `DirectoryIndex` (ie. `index.php`).

I assume all your internal links in the HTML do not include the trailing slash.

You might, however, need to issue a 301 redirect if the slashed URL is accessed directory - but you only really need to do this if these URLs have already been indexed by the search engines or are being linked to.